# Error: couldn't get appropriate GL format for Qt windows

Tags: qt, ubuntu, opengl, ssh

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Through my local machine, I am accessing a remote server (Centos OS) via ssh. On my remote server, I have installed a visualising software named "IMOD".
When I try to open any file using this software, I get the following error. Open link to see error:

[image: Error when I try to open any image using IMOD]

Now it says that make sure OpenGl programs are working.
I tried using glxgears and glxinfo on my local machine. It is working perfectly. My server is Centos OS so I know glxgears won't work on it. So I installed ubuntu on my server via proot. Now glxgears should work when I login into Ubuntu on my server. But it gives following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  21
Current serial number in output stream:  23
```

Also, I have tried setting LIBGL_INDIRECT_ALWAYS=1 in my .bashrc file both on local machine and server.

I am sure the problem is with my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04) because when I ssh my server from Windows laptop: IMOD, glxgears, etc. everthing works perfectly. Even from my friends Ubuntu 14.04 machine it works fine.

Comment: Should be on [su] or [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem.

X-server running on my local machine allows local programs to access OpenGL but when the remote server tries to access, it doesn't allow. It is set to that setting by default.
To allow that make the following changes to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Under Section [SeatDefaults], add

**xserver-command=X +iglx**

If such file doesn't exist then create one and add both lines:

**[SeatDefaults]**

**xserver-command=X +iglx**